# asp:createuserwizard and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, createuserwizard

Is it possible to have 2 createuserwizard controls and call them dynamically? My situation is this:
1. A web application has two types of users - "Client" and "Vendor".
2. They will each have their own separate registration process.
3. On the home page I want two different buttons - Button 1 is "Are you a Client", Button 2 is "Are you a Vendor"
4. Button 1 will load createuserwizard for Client
5. Button 2 will load createuserwizard for Vendor

That's it. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to have 2 separate registration page like VendorRegistration.aspx and ClientRegistration.aspx.
You can also set the controls to visible=false and then set the one you want visible in the button click event.